# What are the benefits of using git submodule

Tags: node.js, git, version-control, npm

Currently trying to figure out what sort of package management to use.

For example I am currently working on a javascript project with nodejs.

I have setup a git submodule and currently trying to figure out which approach to use.

## cloning the repository into the current repository?

```
cd ./somedir && git clone some_repo
```

## using `git submodule` with `npm`?

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "bower install && git submodule init && git submodule update"
}
```

## Why not just add the repo with `npm` package.json `dependencies`?

Like:

```
{ "foo" : "git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish",
  "bar" : "git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish"
}
```

These are the possible ways that I have been thinking about, I am open to something better, and would appreciate any foresight on the issues.

## update

One of the issues that I forsee is if say for example the `node` version differs between where the submodule gets imported/cloned/required. One project might be using node 4.2.4, another may be on 0.12.4, 0.10.4, or 5.6.0. This scenario as far as I can see at the moment can't be solved with just setting a branch, or version tag, or can it?